# How can I control UIView animation repeat cycle?

Tags: ios, macos, animation, uiview

I'm afraid that the title is correct english expression but,

I have an animation on iOS with 4 scenes.

I used `setAnimationDidStopSelector:` method.

Here's the question: How can I make stopping function for the animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 4 and later you should use block based animation. Using these newer methods you can very easily specify some code to run once the animation has finished. For example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations:^{
                     // This code will be animated for 1 second.
                     [anObject setAlpha:0.0];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     // This code will be executed once the animation has completed.
                     [anObject removeFromSuperview];
                 }];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I love your answer

Answer (score 0):

A little ugly, but pretty lazy:
add a flag to know when it should animate, and when not. Put your animation under `if` block (or something same) and just switch flag when you need.